Unable to implement Google Authentication with .Net 8 MVC
I am learning google login feature in .net and implemented it in my sample test application which uses .Net 8 MVC and SQLite DB.
Everything works as expected except the await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(identityUser, extLoginInfo) which always returns a "DuplicateUserName" error code, the error description says "Username xxx@gmail.com is already taken".
I am pasting screenshot below of my two actions methods ExternalLoginand ExternalLoginCallBack. The problem happens in the second method, I have highlighted the error in QuickWatch window which you can see in the Screenshot 2.
Screenshot 1 ExternalLogin
Screenshot 2 ExternalLoginCallBack
Important Note. The screenshots show methods in controller. I have implemented signinmanager and usermanager in repository layer and calling the identity methods from controller using service layer. Therefore, in the screenshot, the method which has the breakpoint on line 103 calls the actual method i.e
_userManager.AddLoginAsync(identityUser, extLoginInfo)

Not sure why I get this error ? Tried other posts to find out the cause but nothing worked.
Will be very thankful to anyone who can help me ? Thank you in advance.
Scenario 1
I tried with existing users that I registered using my application registration page. These users are saved as expected in AspNetUsers Table. Now if I use the same user to login using google authentication screen, it does not create an entry in AspNetUserLogin table.
Scenario 2
I also tried with new gmail email id that is not registered in my AspNetUsers table, and used it to directly login through google authentication however, it also does not create an entry in AspNetUserLogin table. However this new user is added successfully in my AspNetUsers table.
In both the scenarios the error is same "DuplicateUserName".
@YuningDuan: Thank you for the advice. Below are the answers for your questions which might help you to have a better insight into what I implemented:
1. Do you want to use the application for users to log in to Google ?

I want users to login to my application using Google / Facebook / Twitter. So far I added authentication for all the three providers. But all having the same issue

Program.cs:
// google authentication
var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GoogleClientId");
var clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GoogleClientSecret");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = clientId;
    options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
}).AddFacebook(fboptions =>
{
    fboptions.AppId = builder.Configuration["Auth:Facebook:AppId"].ToString(); ;
    fboptions.AppSecret = builder.Configuration["Auth:Facebook:AppSecret"].ToString();
}).AddTwitter(twitter =>
{
    twitter.ConsumerKey = builder.Configuration["Auth:Twitter:ConsumerKey"];
    twitter.ConsumerSecret = builder.Configuration["Auth:Twitter:ConsumerSecret"];
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IReadFileService, ReadFileService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFileReadRepo, FileReadRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoleService, RoleService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExternalLoginProviderService, ExternalLoginProviderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IExternalLoginProviderRepository, ExternalLoginProviderRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

appsettings.json:
"Auth": {
  "Facebook": {
    "AppId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "AppSecret": "xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "Twitter": {
    "ConsumerKey": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "ConsumerSecret": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
  }
}

2. Do you want to register multiple accounts with the same google account?

No. If a user is not registered at all in my application AspNetUsers table, and if he/she signs in using their social media account then I want to save their details in AspNetUsers table and AspNetUserLogin table. UserId from AspNetUsers table is a foreign key in AspNetUserLogin table. The issue here is, it authenticates using social media perfectly and makes an entry in AspNetUsers table, but does not add the entry of the user in AspNetUserLogin table. It gives an error saying AspNetUserLogin table has a user already existing with the username - "DuplicateUserName" even when the table is empty.

3. Is there a Google authentication configuration configured when you use your new Google ID to register for the test ?

Yes. It is configured. See my answer in questions 1 above.

4. Does the Google account already exist in the database?

No. I was trying with empty AspNetUsers table.Logging the user directly with social media login like google, facebook and twitter.

5. Can you provide more information about it and share your AddExternalLoginUser method and GetExternalLogInInfo ?
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallBack", "Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });

    var authProperties = _externalLoginProviderService.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProps(provider, redirectUrl);
    
    
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, authProperties);                     
}


[AllowAnonymous]        
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallBack(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) 
    {
        returnUrl = Url.Content("~/");
    }

    var loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
        ExternalLoginProviders = await _externalLoginProviderService.GetExternalLoginProviders(),
    };

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(remoteError)) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Errors during login : ", remoteError);
        
        return View("Login", loginViewModel);
    }
    
    var loginInfo = await _externalLoginProviderService.GetExternalLoginInfo();

    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", $"Error loading information from external login provider");
        return View("Login", loginViewModel);
    }

    var signInResult = await _externalLoginProviderService.SignInUsingExternalLogin(
                                        loginInfo.ProviderDisplayName, loginInfo.ProviderKey, false, false);

    if (signInResult.Succeeded)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) ? RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "User") : LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        var claimFromExternal = loginInfo.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email) ??  // Google or Facebook
                                loginInfo.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name); // Twitter
        
        if (claimFromExternal != null) 
        {
            var user = await _userService.GetUserByEmail(claimFromExternal);                    
            
            if (user == null) 
            {                                              
               await _userService.CreateExternalUserInLocal(claimFromExternal);                                             
            }

            var userLoginInfo = new UserLoginInfo(loginInfo.LoginProvider, loginInfo.ProviderKey, loginInfo.ProviderDisplayName);
            
            var identityUser = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = claimFromExternal,
                Email = claimFromExternal                        
            };
            
            var result = await _userService.AddExternalLoginUser(identityUser, userLoginInfo);
            await _userService.SignInExternalUser(identityUser);

            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) ? RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "User") : LocalRedirect(returnUrl); 
        }
    }

    return View("Login", loginViewModel);
}


You can check if your database link is correct and if there is the same username and space in your database table. In your description do you want to use the application for users to log in to Google? Do you want to register multiple accounts with the same google account? Is there a Google authentication configuration configured when you use your new Google ID to register for the test? And does the Google account already exist in the database? If that's all right, can you provide more information about it and share your AddExternalLoginUser method and GetExternalLogInInfo?

@YuningDuan: Thank you for the help. I have edited my post to include more details regarding your questions. Let me know if you any questions.

Through the code you provided, you can check whether there are database insertion operations in your service methods, such as AddExternalLoginUser, GetExternalLogInInfo, and CreateExternalUserInLocal, and check if there are repeated insertions.

The AddLoginAsync method also verifies the existence of the user in the aspnetuser table. If the user exists, it returns a failure, and no row is added to the aspnetuserlogin table.
Also refer to ASP.NET Identity AddLoginAsync fails - Name/Email X is already taken

If you see my description, I have mentioned also that I have tried by truncating both the tables and the issue persists still.

Did the link I provided helped?

Thanks for the link. I tried the other suggestions. But it still does not work. The only difference I see, is I am using SQLite DB and others are using MS SQL SERVER. However, it does not matter which relational database server I use. It should work regardless of that.
